# SPFx Data Sources besides SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, dataverse

Besides using a SharePoint list, are there other easy to use options to use as a data source for SPFx. I know some use Azure but that has an extra cost with it. I have found very little in how to use Dataverse as a data source and not sure if this advisable. I'm just looking for something that can hold more than 5000 records and not as accessible as a SharePoint list.

Comment: SharePoint lists can store up to [30 million items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#items-in-lists-and-libraries). The issue is with retrieving items as a view is limited to 5k items. However, placing indexes on your filter/sort/group columns should mitigate performance. There are other strategies to retrieve large amounts of items (search, paging, etc.), though SPFx returning that many items at once client side seems like a bad idea regardless of data source.

Comment: If the issue is more about the accessibility of lists, then there are things that can be done to mitigate that (delegation, permissions, list settings, removing from search, etc.) but it's never going to be as clean as a database in SQL. Dataverse is worth looking into. There is an API and examples of using it with SPFx though there are definitely costs. Dataverse for Teams with Power Apps however, may be a better use case for both ease of implementation and cost.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there other easy to use options as a data source for SPFx, but I think all of them will require you to pay some additional costs.

In terms of Dataverse, you could use the [Microsoft Dataverse Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/overview) to interact with Dataverse data. I haven't looked at this API in a while, but my recollection is that it's kind of klunky and not super intuitive.

I think the most common alternatives to SharePoint for data storage would be Azure SQL, Azure Cosmos DB, Azure Table Storage, and/or Azure Blob Storage. It should be relative easy to find documentation/resources that describe how to consume these data sources from SPFx.